# How to update a list after item was edited using flow and coroutine in android?

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, clean-architecture

I have a simple repo `SimpleRepository` which fetch data from server using retrofit. The data is a simple list of items or a details of some item.

Now I have a edit screen when user can change the item name. So after user clicks SaveButton the simple rest call is called and the server update the item.

But the item on the list isn't updated.

The repo looks like this:

```
interface SimpleRepo {

  fun getAllItems(): Flow<List<Item>>
 
  fun getItem(id: String) : Flow<Item>

  fun updateItemName(id: String, newName: String): Flow<Boolean> //true if server changed the value

  fun updateItemTitle(id: String, newTitle: String): Flow<Boolean> //true if server changed the value

  fun updateItemSubtitle(id: String, newSubtitle: String): Flow<Boolean> //true if server changed the value

  fun updateItemDescription(id: String, newDescription: String): Flow<Boolean> //true if server changed the value
}
```

The repo is used by use cases and the use cases are used by view models.

My question is: how to implement the SimpleRepo to get new element form flows after one of the `updateItemXxxx()` method was called?

Answer (score 2):

you could try something like that

> onSuccess, updates, api implementation aren't here

I suggest to change all your updates methods as `suspend` except if you need to get multiple emits

```kotlin
class RepositoryImplementation (private val api:API) : ConversationsRepository{
  val flowOfItems = MutableStateFlow<List<Item>>(emptyList())

  fun getAllItems(): Flow<List<Item>> {
     //you could add also a property in `getAllItems` to do an invalidation or not
     CoroutineScope(Job() + Dispatchers.Default).launch {
            api.getAllItems().onSuccess {
               flowOfItems.update { it }
            }
        }
     return flowOfItems
  }

  suspend fun updateItemName(id: String, newName: String): Boolean {
     apiUpdateItemName(id,newName).onSuccess{
        //depending on your api, if you have the whole list again
        //update the list in `flowOfItems`, or update the list with the change only
     }
  }
}
```

as the `getAllItems()` returns always the same flow and you are writing updates to that flow, it should observer properly on your UI the elements

Comment: thx. but question: how to pass errors which are emited in case on failed getAllItems()?

Comment: you could change the response to be Flow<Result<Item>> / Flow<Either<Item,Failure>> there are countless examples of implementations like that ...

Answer (score 0):

I found a working solution. See below.

Key was:

- make refresher global
- set replay to 1 in shared flow
- always call tryEmit

So short implementation:

```
 private val refresher = MutableSharedFlow<Unit>(replay = 1)

 @OptIn(FlowPreview::class)
 class SimpleRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(
    private val remote: RemoteDataSource,
 ) : SimpleRepo {

 init {  refresher.tryEmit(Unit) }

 override fun getAllItems(): Flow<List<Item>> = refresher
     .flatMapConcat {
         flow {
            val items = remote
                .getItems()
                 .body()
                 ?.map { Item(it.id, it.name) }
                 ?: emptyList()

             emit(items)
         }
     }

 override fun getItem(id: String) = refresher.flatMapConcat {
     flow {
         val item = remote.getItem(id)
             .body()
             ?.let {
                 Item(it.id, it.name)
             }!!
         emit(item)
     }
 }


 override fun updateItemName(id: String, newName: String): Flow<Boolean> = flow {
     remote.updateName(
         id = id,
         name = newName,
      )
     refresher.tryEmit(Unit)
     emit(true)
  }
}
```